# Compare value to get largest number in every object looping JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with how to compare value to get largest number in more than one object.

For example i have 3 object (and this object can increment more than 3):

These each object saved in `acc` variable

```
[
    { "key": 1, "value": 1 },
    { "key": 1, "value": 3 },
    { "key": 1, "value": 6 },
]


[
    { "key": 2, "value": 2 },
    { "key": 2, "value": 5 },
    { "key": 2, "value": 9 },
]


[
    { "key": 3, "value": 1 },
    { "key": 3, "value": 2 },
    { "key": 3, "value": 3 },
]
```

First i get the last value from each object with `console.log(acc[acc.length - 1].value);`

and it will print:

```
6
9
2
```

Then i don't know how to compare the numbers? And get result:

```
{ "key": 2, "value": 9 }
```

I have try `console.log(Math.max(acc[acc.length - 1].value));`, but its not working because that number is not inside one array.

This is screenshot if i log `console.log(acc)`

[image]

Comment: What is the expected result if you have more than two objects with the same max value? Is `{ "key": 2, "value": 9 }` the expected result because the value of `9` is the largest value across all objects?

Comment: yes i want to get the largest value, and also get they key "2"

Comment: So what if you have 2 objects with the same largest value?

Comment: that 2 object will return

Comment: So you are actually after an array as your output then? Not just a single object, so your expected output is more like `[{ "key": 2, "value": 9 }]`, which can potentially grow to include multiple objects depending on your input.

Comment: yes thats right sir

Answer (score 2):

First merge all the nested objects by [`.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and perform [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) operation on them. in every iteration look `b.value` is greater than the object value of accumulator `a.value`, if it's the case we need to update the object of the accumulator `a`.

```js
const arr = [[ { "key": 1, "value": 1 }, { "key": 1, "value": 3 }, { "key": 1, "value": 6 }, ], [ { "key": 2, "value": 2 }, { "key": 2, "value": 5 }, { "key": 2, "value": 9 }, ], [ { "key": 3, "value": 1 }, { "key": 3, "value": 2 }, { "key": 3, "value": 3 }, ]];

console.log(arr.flat().reduce((a,b)=>(b.value > a.value ? b : a)));
```

New requirement:

```js
const arr = [[
    { "key": 1, "value": 1 },
    { "key": 1, "value": 3 },
    { "key": 1, "value": 6 },
    { "key": 3, "value": 6 },
],
[
    { "key": 2, "value": 2 },
    { "key": 2, "value": 5 },
    { "key": 2, "value": 9 },
],
[
    { "key": 3, "value": 1 },
    { "key": 3, "value": 2 },
    { "key": 3, "value": 3 },
]];


let results = [{key: -1, value: -1}]; //initial value I assume data don't have a value less than -1

arr.forEach((item) => { //Simulating your current situation
  item.forEach(it => { //here we get an array in each iteration
    if (it.value > results[0].value) {
      results = [it];
    }
    else if (it.value === results[0].value) {
      results.push(it);
    }
  });
});

console.log(results);
```

Comment: thanks before sir, but how to put the object inside that ```const arr```?

Comment: Because this only return the largest value on each object, not from across all object sir. With this code i get return ```{  "key": 1, "value": 6 }``` and ```{  "key": 2, "value": 9 }``` but my expectation is only ```{  "key": 2, "value": 9 }``` should be return

Comment: @ASHafizullah can you please explain a bit what do you mean by "how to put the object inside that `const arr`"

Comment: sorry i mean, each object is not inside one array sir. If we print to console log, its like ```object 1``` then ```object 2``` then ```object 3``` (and its looping)...

Comment: @ASHafizullah seems like you want to get the result inside an array because we can have multiple occurrences of the biggest values like `[{key: "1", value: 9},{key: 2, value: 9}]` right?

Comment: thats right, but also, the object is one by one inside ```acc``` variable, because its have looping. For example, ```console.log(acc)``` its will like this screenshot:https://ibb.co/cgL9BqV

Comment: Because i try ```console.log(arr.flat().reduce((a,b)=>(b.value > a.value ? b : a)));``` its not compare with accross all object, but its only compare in that 1 object

Comment: @ASHafizullah seems like I understand do you mean by that. That means you are looping through something and at a time it gives you an array and you want to track the objects which has the highest value across all array of objects, right?

Comment: yes that right sir. How to do that...

Comment: well, let me code it!

Comment: @ASHafizullah I have updated the answer, can you pls check it out?

Comment: okay let me try sir

Comment: it say ```item.forEach is not a function``` sir

Comment: @ASHafizullah I just tried to simulate your situation, in my case I'm iterating item array. in your case it's maybe `acc`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249903/discussion-between-ashafizullah-and-asraf).